# Two questions about compiling order of packages codes

Tags: packages, compiling, package-options

I have a question about compiling order of packages. For example consider a package (for instance `tocloft`) and I have the following document:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{2em}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{foo}
\section{bar}
\subsection{foobar}
\end{document}
```

> **Q1:** In the compiling steps of this file, it checks all lines of `tocloft` package or just the lines that are involved?

And I want to know,

> **Q2:** how much is different the compiling time of 1000 (or 10000) lines `\renewcommand` ed commands and its original definition? e.g. Are the compiling time of the following two codes equal?

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{command}{new}  %redefine all commands of book.cls
\makeatother

    \begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{foo}
    \section{bar}
    \subsection{foobar}
    \end{document}
```

and

```
 \documentclass{book}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{foo}
\section{bar}
\subsection{foobar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: »ed«? Typo? I don’t understand the second question.

Comment: "renewcommanded"!!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean in Q2, please? I should also note that it is in general *strongly* preferred to ask only one question per question. Especially since there is no risk of TeXnical interference here. See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864.

Comment: Ad Q1 (if I understand correctly): `tocloft` is loaded the same way no matter which commands you actually use in your document. Nothing that comes after `\usepackage{tocloft}` can influence how the package is loaded. (Some packages may do some things dynamically depending on which engine you use and a few other things and that can mean that not all bits of the package are loaded in all configurations, but I'd say that in general it is fair for most packages to assume that they are always loaded and processed the same way.)

Comment: Well, in general you'd assume that reading a longer file and executing all the `\renewcommand`s would take longer than reading a shorter file and not executing those redefinitions. *But* if you manage to redefine macros that are actually used in the document in a way that the redefinition is faster than the original definition you might manage to gain some speed (of course it is tricky to find implementations that are faster *and* do the right thing).

Comment: are you asking if it's faster to load a package or define all the package commands using `\newcommand`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A1** All the lines of packages are processed. When I developed `tocloft` I made some errors which were flagged at `\usepackage{tocloft}`.

**A2** I think that nowadays in general, unless you are doing something well out of the ordinary, there will be little perceived difference in processing times; of course it would have been different in the 1980's